# Borel-Tanner distribution with finite bound

Tags: probability-distributions

I'd like to model proportion of certain species in a popualtion with Borel-Tanner distribution: $\frac{e^{-m}m^{m-1}}{m!}$, its support is defined on $\{1,2,...\}$, but I need finite bound. Could anyone help me with finding the finite sum $\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{e^{-m}m^{m-1}}{m!}$?

Comment: The Borel-Tanner distribution is not given by the formula you write. Furthermore the sum of the series of general term $\mathrm{e}^{-m}m^m/m!$ is infinite and in particular, not $1$.

Comment: I edited it accordingly

Comment: If the (modified) weights you consider sum to $1$, you could show why.

Comment: I need the sum $\sum_{m=1}^{\mu} \frac{e^{-m}m^{m-1}}{m!}$, and I haven't found it so far